# SourceForge file releases

Tags: rss, sourceforge

I would like to automate updating from SourceForge. This was working for a while

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/rss?path=/Base/x86_64
```

However I realized that the RSS feed has a max of 100 items. So if the chosen
`path` was last updated before that then it will not be on RSS, and will return

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

[§ File Releases](http://sf.net/p/forge/documentation/API%20-%20Classic/#file-releases)

So can I access a SourceForge file list with another "API"? I would prefer to
not have to scrape the page like an animal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround, but PowerShell can easily parse HTML

```sh
$base = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/Base/x86_64'
```

Example, get latest file

```sh
$base.Links | ? class -eq name | select -fir 1 -exp href
```

Get latest file matching `tar`

```sh
$base.Links | ? href -match tar | select -fir 1 -exp href
```